# Google Sheets Return Any(All) Row Value(s) For MAX-GROUP Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am looking to return non-grouped row values from a query of a table sorted by the MAX value of a column, within a group.

**DATA TABLE**
| NAME | ASSET | ACTION | DATE |
|--|--|--|--|
| JOE | CAR | BOUGHT | 1/1/2020 |
| JANE | HORSE | BOUGHT | 1/1/2021 |
| JOE | HORSE | BOUGHT | 2/1/2021 |
| JANE | HORSE | SOLD | 3/1/2021 |
| JOE | CAR | SOLD | 1/1/2022 |
| JOE | CAR | BOUGHT | 2/1/2022 |

For the table above, I presented the following code.
`=QUERY(A1:D5,"SELECT A,B,C,D, MAX(D) GROUP BY A,B",TRUE)`

The following **TARGET TABLE** is output I'm looking for:
| NAME | ASSET | ACTION | DATE |
|--|--|--|--|
| JANE | HORSE | SOLD | 3/1/2021 |
| JOE | HORSE | BOUGHT | 2/1/2021 |
| JOE | CAR | BOUGHT | 2/1/2022 |

However, because 'C' is not included in the GROUP, the formula returns an error. *"Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: C"*

If I were to omit COL C & D, "ACTION" & "DATE" from the SELECT: `=QUERY(A1:D5,"SELECT A,B, MAX(D) GROUP BY A,B",TRUE)` , I have the correct record rows, but am missing the STATUS.

**MAX-DATE TABLE**
| NAME | ASSET | max DATE |
|--|--|--|
| JANE | HORSE | 3/1/2021 |
| JOE | HORSE | 2/1/2021 |
| JOE | CAR | 2/1/2022 |

OR, when I add COL C as a "PIVIOT": `=QUERY(A1:D5,"SELECT A,B, MAX(D) GROUP BY A,B PIVOT C",TRUE)`I have the correct record rows, but do not have the 'current' STATUS within the record row.

**PIVOT ACTION TABLE**
| NAME | ASSET | BOUGHT | SOLD |
|--|--|--|--|
| JANE | HORSE | 1/1/2021 | 3/1/2021 |
| JOE | HORSE | 2/1/2021 |  |
| JOE | CAR | 2/1/2022 | 1/1/2022 |

Still I have not found a method to create my **TARGET TABLE**.
Am I overlooking a method to include a non-grouped field into a query using MAX()? Or is it impossible within Google Sheets Query without JOIN functions?

*(I hope it is obvious that I desire to apply this to a large and dynamic dataset.)*

Thank you for your insight. Cheers!

Comment: you can warp a query with another query: ```=QUERY(QUERY(A1:D5,"SELECT A,B,C,MAX(D) GROUP BY A,B,C",1),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col4")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that flexible to work with QUERYs with its aggregation requisites and so on.

You can create a filter, by comparing column D with a "fictional" column created with BYROW: `= BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,MAXIFS($D$2:$D,$A$2:$A,each,$B$2:$B,OFFSET(each,,1))))`

That would look like this (I highlighted the matches and added extra rows for reference):

[image]

Then, you can set this filter (don't create this column, it's just a visualization of what I did):

```
=FILTER(A2:D,D2:D = BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,MAXIFS($D$2:$D,$A$2:$A,each,$B$2:$B,OFFSET(each,,1)))))
```

This way, you're comparing the dates with the maximum for each category

[image: ![enter image description here]